# How to dynamically change ng-class when ng-model value changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code, I would like add classes to 'label' when the input box is empty and not empty.
So,I'm checking input box is null or not and add classes according to this.
It works when page reloads, but classes aren't changing when i make input into null.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input-border" ng-model="userProfile.name"/> {{userProfile.name}}
    <label for="name" ng-class="userProfile.name === null ?'custom-label-no-content':'custom-label-content'" class="xs-keep-label-in-place">Display Name</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: `ng-class="{ 'custom-label-no-content': userProfile.name === null,  'custom-label-content': userProfile.name !== null }"`

Comment: @haxxxton you're so fast. I'm about to answer this. Wkwkwk.

Comment: @haxxxton Its not working, maybe because the changes happened in ng-model isn't binded with ng-class.

Comment: can you provide your controller code please

Comment: This has nothing to do with controller, all i need is to add two different classes to label when input box is null and not null.

Comment: @hasi, if your controller code is not correctly setting the ngModel value, then the ngClass binding wont "hear" the change.. I cannot rule out that there is not an issue with your controller code unless you provide it.

Comment: Are you sure that your check for `null` is what you actually want to do? are you trying to check for "no content" in the value? because deleting all content in an `<input type="text" />` sets the `ngModel` to `""`. So you'd actually want to check for `userProfile.name === null || userProfile.name.length === 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is an answer without needing a controller,**

Since it is a text box, you should use

**`userProfile.name.length and !userProfile.name.length`**

```
ng-class="{ 'custom-label-no-content': userProfile.name.length, 'custom-label-content': !userProfile.name.length }"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
.custom-label-no-content {
    color:white;
    background-color:lightblue;
    padding:20px;
    font-family:"Courier New";
}
.custom-label-content {
    background-color:coral;
    padding:40px;
    font-family:Verdana;
}
</style>
<body ng-app="">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input-border" ng-model="userProfile.name"/> {{userProfile.name}}
  <label for="name" ng-class="{ 'custom-label-no-content': userProfile.name.length, 'custom-label-content': !userProfile.name.length }" class="xs-keep-label-in-place">Display Name</label>
  </div>
  

</body>
</html>
```

**PLEASE RUN THE ABOVE SNIPPET**

[**HERE IS A WORKING DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/rWbUFNUON1OO75JksBGF?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you Sravan.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a number of ways.

## [1. Function in your Controller (recommended)](https://jsfiddle.net/10bvdk9k/)

**html**

```
<label for="name" ng-class="labelClass()" class="xs-keep-label-in-place">Display Name</label>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.labelClass = function(){
    var classes = [];
    if($scope.userProfile.name === null){
        classes.push('custom-label-no-content');
    }else{
        classes.push('custom-label-content');
    }
    return classes;
}
```

## 2. Expression with single curly brace

**html**

```
<label for="name" ng-class="{ 'custom-label-no-content': userProfile.name === null, 'custom-label-content': userProfile.name !== null }" class="xs-keep-label-in-place">Display Name</label>
```

## 3. Switch statement with hardcoded class

**html**

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-switch="userProfile.name === null">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input-border" ng-model="userProfile.name"/> {{userProfile.name}}
    <label for="name" ng-switch-when="true" class="custom-label-no-content xs-keep-label-in-place">Display Name</label>
    <label for="name" ng-switch-when="false" class="custom-label-content xs-keep-label-in-place">Display Name</label>
</div>
```

Personally, I would recommend option 1 as it conforms to the MVC pattern, where your "logic" should remain in your controller, while your "view" code remains purely for display.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .custom-label-no-content {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
        .custom-label-content {
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
    </style>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input-border" ng-model="userProfile.name" /> {{userProfile.name}}
        <label for="name" ng-class="userProfile.name === '' ?'custom-label-no-content':'custom-label-content'" class="xs-keep-label-in-place">Display Name</label>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.userProfile = {};
            $scope.userProfile.name = '';
            
        });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```